# using CTRL+T of fzf to put commands on command line

Tags: command-line, fzf

I keep a list of frequently used command snipets in a file (called sniplist) that I use to cut/copy what I need onto the command line for further editing before execution. I thought I would leverage the CTRL+T option of fzf to do the job more easily. The relevant default environment variable is:

```
export FZF_CTRL_T_COMMAND="find . -type f -printf '%P\n'"
```

So I simply changed this to:

```
export FZF_CTRL_T_COMMAND="cat ~/sniplist"
```

This presents me with my sniplist as expected. I select a line and it lands on the command line -- but with all non-alphanum characters escaped with a backslash. For example, a line like:

```
seq 0 4 100 | fzf --preview="date -d '{}  week 18 april 2023'"
```

is placed on the command line as:

```
seq\ 0\ 4\ 100\ \|\ fzf\ --preview=\"date\ -d\ \'\{\}\ \ week\ 18\ april\ 2023\'\"
```

How can I avoid this unwanted effect?

Comment: You'll likely need to disable that quoting done in the related function defined for your shell (see [there](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/a62fe3df6f715630f0fd6ee6879573e107bc45a0/shell/key-bindings.bash#L29) for bash for instance). Or create your own separate one.